# Typecheck params.id using PropTypes in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

In ReactJS, you can access the ID passed to a route with `{this.props.params.id}`. However, how do you use PropTypes to typecheck the `params.id` property? The below doesn't work and throws an error.

```
Person.propTypes = {
  params.id: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `React.PropTypes.shape` to verify an object's properties -- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Something like this should work:

```js
Person.propTypes = {
  params: React.PropTypes.shape({
    id: React.PropTypes.string
  })
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Wished that page had more details about `shape`... only referenced in code comments.

Comment: Np! It certainly comes in handy